# checking number modulo 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm, floating-point, modulo

I saw the following:
`if (n % 1 || n < 2) ...` in some [code](https://gist.github.com/ehsanamini/d6f3c3709841a2dab94fda4758d07e8f).

The question is what good is the test `n % 1`? I presume it is (false)0 for all non-zero integers, in which case it would be pointless to disjoin it with anything as it would be equivalent to its disjunct (`(false || p) == p`, right?). Is it checking if the number is an int?  Is it a shortcut for `!isNaN(n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript all numbers are `float`s so `n%1` returns remainder of `n/1` so it returns the fractional part of `n` something like `n-floor(n)` for positive `n`. So:

```
if (n % 1 || n < 2)
```

should select all fractional numbers and all integers less then 2 (which are not valid inputs for integer IsPrime method).